# Nginx, ModX, and Friendly URLs (URL re-writing)

Tags: nginx, modx

I'm migrating a number of ModX Evo websites from my old webserver (Debian / Apache / ISPConfig3) to my new webserver (Debian / Nginx / ISPConfig3).

ISPConfig allows you to add Nginx directives to each vhost, and this is where I've added the following code:

```
if ($http_user_agent ~* "internal dummy connection") {
  return 403;
}

location /manager {
}

location /assets {
}

location / {
  if (!-f $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1;
  }
}
```

When I turn Friendly URLs *and* Friendly Aliases on, and set my preferred suffix to .html, then preview a given page (e.g. http://example.com/friendly-url.html), the browser attempts to serve up an HTML page as a download.

(If you download this file and open in a text editor, turns out the file has the exact contents of index.php in the ModX installation root).

What am I doing wrong? How is URL re-writing achieved in nginx? Is this even a URL re-writing issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use nginx directives from this page - http://rtfm.modx.com/display/revolution20/Nginx+Server+Config ?